# New Input does not change FormGroup disable property on Sub Component

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms

I have two components Parent and Child.

Parent stores the state of the formGroup used in the child component.
Each time I receive new data from external source, I pass this data through template and construct new FormGroup and decide based on one property if FormGroup is enabled or disabled.
New data are changed as I want but the disabled/enabled state does not.

My code:

**Child component**

```
@Input() edvForm: FormGroup;
@Input() isBlocMainSupport: boolean;
@Input() data: Data;

ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
   this.setForm();
}

setForm() {
   ...
   this.edvForm.addControl(
      'supportType',
      new FormControl({ value: supportType, disabled: !this.isBlocMainSupport })
   );
}
```

**Parent component**

```
edvForm: FormGroup;
isBlocMainSupport = true;
data: Data;

...

ngOnInit(): void {
   this.sourceEvent$
      .pipe(takeUntil(this.destroy$))
      .subscribe(newData => {
        this.newGraphicElements([newData]);
      });
}

...

newGraphicElements(newData: Data[]) {

   this.reset();
   ...
   this.data = newData[0];
   this.isBlocMainSupport = myCondition ? true : false;
}

...

reset() {
   this.edvForm = new FormGroup({});
}
```

**Parent template**

```
<child-comp
   *ngIf="isTheRightChild"
   [data]="data"
   [edvForm]="edvForm"
   [isBlocMainSupport]="isBlocMainSupport"
></child-comp>
```

To resume, data are well passed and change everytime as needed.
But, disable state is not applied with : "disabled: !this.isBlocMainSupport"

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution on github:  [formGroup disable()/enable() does not work right after init #22556](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/22556#issuecomment-667048665)

The problem is the change detector.
The following code is working :

```
this.changeDetector.detectChanges(); // use it before using disable/enable
this.form.controls['name'].disable();
```